# Cannot call App Clip with Local User Experience

Tags: swift, apple-appclips

I am trying to test an App Clip [sample](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-apple-app-clips-sample-app) on My iPhone with iOS 12.2. I can build the sample codes successfully , I configured the following for the Local User Experience.

Local User Experience Settings:
[image]

When I scan the QR Code generated by "https://fruits.com/check?fruit_name=bananas", I didn't see the App Clip prompted.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Do you have a question about programming, or is this question about the linked GitHub repo? In case of the former, please post your code here that doesn't work and you need help with. In case of the latter, it would be better to open an issue on the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution: we need to scan the QR code with the QR code native scanner in the Control Center.
Thanks.